# Why is the function not providing new value in each loop?

Tags: c++, function, loops

In this code, I want to call a function within a loop, to provide a new random number in each iteration. However, it does not work, the output is always the same, like "2 2 2 2" or "5 5 5 5". What's going wrong?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int vertex (int x) {

srand(time(NULL));
x = rand()%10+1;

}


int main()
{

const int size =4;
int a;
int arr[size];

 for (int i=1;i<=size;i++){
        arr[i] = vertex(a) ;
    cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You are seeding `rand` with `time(NULL)`, and there is not enough work being done for that value to change inside your loop. This is causing the value to come back the same (i.e. the first value for `rand` seeded with `time(NULL)`) on each call of `vertex`.

Instead of seeding it in the `vertex` function, seed it once, in your `main` function.

You will also need to make a few modifications to your code in order for it to work, as currently it will not compile.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <ctime>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int vertex() {
    // x parameter removed, was not actually being used
    return (rand() % 10 + 1);
}


int main() {

    const int size = 4;
    int a;
    int arr[size];
    // seeding rand once, prior to usage
    srand(time(NULL));
    // initial i value changed to 0, and changed condition to 'less-than', otherwise you'd end up trying to reference an invalid index (size is 4, index is 0-3)
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        arr[i] = vertex();
        cout << arr[i] << " ";
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: It will not work. In `int vertex(int x)` new x value is discarded when leaving function.

Comment: It will not even compile because your `int vertex(int x)` does not return anything.

Comment: Ah, so it is..I must admit, it's been a while since I've touched C++. Will update my answer.

Comment: I've updated and tested my answer, and it is functioning as expected. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You should not call `srand(time(NULL))` every time inside function `vertex`.

Instead, call it **once**, in function `main` (before the loop).

An additional (unrelated) problem in your code is:

```
for (int i=1;i<=size;i++)
```

You need to change it to:

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++)
```

And finally, in function `vertex` you need to `return x` (though, I'm guessing you just forgot to write it in your question, because I cannot see how your program would have been compiled otherwise)...

Answer (score 0):

You need to call `srand(time(NULL));` only once

```
int main()
{
    srand(time(NULL));
    ...
```

Also, change your function to:

```
int vertex () {
   return(rand()%10+1);
}
```

Thirdly, as pointed out, you have an off by one error in your array.

```
for (int i=1;i<=size;i++){
```

Change this to:

```
for (int i=0;i<size;i++){
```

Answer (score 0):

1.You should call `srand(time(NULL))` only once!

2.Change your `vertex` function to

```
int vertex (int x) {
    return rand()%10+1;
}
```

3.`int arr[size];` has indexes from 0 to `size-1`. Change

```
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
```

to

```
for (int i = 1; i < size; i++)
```